# Join including count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

events and events_actions

```
events columns:

 event_id
 user_id
 event_name

events_actions columns:

 action_id
 user_id
 event_name
```

they have one common field in both tables which is event_name

I want to show all events for a user, but, only if they have some event_actions linked to them (linked by event_name)

I can do this by pulling all events by user_id and then before displaying make sure same name event_actions > 0 but is there a way to do it in one SQL query?

I am using MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from events ev
where exists (select 1 from event_actions ea where ev.event_name = ea.event_name)
```

or

```
select ev.event_name,count(ea.action_id)
from events ev,event_actions ea
where ev.event_name = ea.event_name
group by ea.event_name
having count(ea.action_id) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there should be `event_id` on the table `events_actions`, not `event_name`. Well, assuming that `event_name` is unique, you can do this query:

```
SELECT E.user_id, E.event_name
FROM dbo.events E
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT event_name, user_id FROM dbo.events_actions) EA
ON E.user_id = EA.user_id AND E.event_name = EA.event_name
```